# Not able to make API call using php CURL

Tags: php, web-services, api, soap

This is the request format for the SOAP request

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelopexmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 

xmlns:sas="http://api.testdemo.in/"> 

<SOAP-ENV:Body> 

 <sas:Login> 

 <Username>user</Username> 

 <Password>password</Password> 

 </sas:Login> 

</SOAP-ENV:Body> 

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I tried the following codes below,

```
$xml = '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:sas="http://api.testdemo.in/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <sas:Login>
 <Username>user</Username>
 <Password>password</Password>
 </sas:Login>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

$url = "http://api.testdemo.in/";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$headers = array();
array_push($headers, "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
array_push($headers, "Accept: text/xml");
array_push($headers, "Cache-Control: no-cache");
array_push($headers, "Pragma: no-cache");
if($xml != null) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml");
    array_push($headers, "Content-Length: " . strlen($xml));
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($response);
print_r($code);
```

This page loaded for sometime and I got '0' on the page.

The actual xml response should be

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelopexmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 

xmlns:sas="http://api.testdemo.in/"> 

<SOAP-ENV:Body> 

 <sas:LoginResponse> 

 <SessionID>FC82329EF6</SessionID> 

 <ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode> 

 <ResponseMessage>Successsful</ResponseMessage>

 </sas:LoginResponse> 

</SOAP-ENV:Body> 

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Im new to SOAP,can't find a better way..I got the above code online,I dont know this is the way a SOAP request should be done.

Please suggest some ways to do it.Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

What you would want to do is to check if there is a curl error by adding this after executing the curl

```
try
{
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if(curl_errno($ch) == "0")    //check if there is an curl error occurred such as unable to connect to host etc
    {
         //do your parsing here

    }
    else
    {
        throw new exception('Curl Error No'.curl_errno($ch).' Error Description:'.curl_error($ch));
    }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

From here on, determine whether if it is a curl error. If it is, post the error.

Comment: Thanks,I tried your code and I got a curl error as 'Curl Error No28 Error Description:Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds' .Any idea why that would happen

Comment: that is because the cURL default timeout is 30seconds, try to add this 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,500); //set curl timeout to 500
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);   //halt infinite redirection